# MySQL : check if a "value" is in one field but is not in another one?

Tags: mysql, string, substring, find-in-set

I have a table like this:

```
id  |  value1  | value2
-------------------------
1   | a,b,c,d  | a,d,e,f
-------------------------
2   | d,e,f,a  | 
-------------------------
3   | a,x,y,z  | d,e,f
```

How can I get all rows that have "a" in [value1] but don't have "a" in [value2]?
It should be this:

```
2   | d,e,f,a  | 
-------------------------
3   | a,x,y,z  | d,e,f
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's simply. What have you tried?

Comment: delimited fields are the devil.

Answer (score 1):

You should think about normalization and never store data as comma separated string. However in this case you may use `find_in_set`, which is not efficient in long run. So while you are normalizing data (assuming you will do it), in the meanwhile you may use the following.

```
mysql> select find_in_set('a','a,b,c,d') as pos ;
+-----+
| pos |
+-----+
|   1 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select find_in_set('a','d,e,f') as pos ;
+-----+
| pos |
+-----+
|   0 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So the query becomes

```
select * from table_name
where
find_in_set('a',value1) > 0 
and find_in_set('a',value2) = 0
```

Comment: Second find should be on `value2` column. Alternatively, `find_in_set( 'a', value1 ) > find_in_set( 'a', value2 )`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `value1` LIKE '%a%'
AND `value2` NOT LIKE '%a%'
```

Answer (score 0):

if table name is 'test'

```
select * from test where value1 like '%a%' and value2 not like '%a%';
```